# Pydroid на android

Tags: python, android

Меня интересует возможно ли с помощью среды разработки pydroid скомпилировать написанный на ней код в полноценное android приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Да, если использовать kivy или pyQt

Comment: Для kyvy помнется мне нужен был Linux так как толко на нём работает фреймворк Buildozer. Который в свою очередь и кмпелирует простой код в apps. Ну это делается с компа, а я хочу с телефона сразу

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите создать apk с приложением, то нет, но если надо только запустить, то да

Comment: Я пока не очень прошарен и , что такое apk представляю смутно. У меня есть код написанный с библиотекой tkinter. Программа делает вычисления. Как бы из самой IDE всё работает, но хотелось бы по 'взрослому', заходить в программу нажимая на иконку как в обычное приложение.

Comment: Смотрите [здесь](https://learning-python.com/using-tkinter-programs-on-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [Pydroid 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3). В него можно загрузить код и нажать на желтую кнопку и он выполниться, есть даже терминал `Linux`.